# Rails InvalidAuthenticityToken with HTTPS + ELB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, csrf-protection, elastic-load-balancer, authenticity-token

I'm trying to get HTTPS to work for my site, but I'm getting `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` for all post requests. I logged the `form_authenticity_param` and `form_authenticity_token`and they are in fact different.

The SSL is resolved at the Elastic Load Balancer and a non-SSL request is sent to the web app. The expected CSRF token is stored in the cookie-based session, so the sessions for HTTP and HTTPS appear to expect different tokens. When using HTTP on the site, the post/put requests work fine.

I've been stuck on this problem for a bit. Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: Is your problem with `devise/sign_in` or with any other form?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem, but it's not rails.

I fixed the problem by add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` in my nginx.config

```
  location @videos {
    proxy_pass http://videos;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue interestingly enough after Rails 5.2 upgrade for whatever reason. Adding the above resolved the issue

Comment: @beaorn It may be related that with Rails 5.1 the option `action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check` is enabled by default.